# JAXB throws zero-arg-constructor error for @XmlTransient field 

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink

I have a class which declares a Joda Time `DateTime`  field.

However, the value of this isn't set by the unmarhsalling process, instead it's set later in the `afterUnmarhsal` method.

Therefore, the field is marked `XmlTransient`:

```
@XmlTransient
private DateTime startTime;
```

However, when trying to start up, I'm faced with this error:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:  Exception Description: The class
>   org.joda.time.DateTime$Property requires a zero argument constructor
>   or a specified factory method.  Note that non-static inner classes do
>   not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.
>    - with linked exception: [Exception [EclipseLink-50001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913) ...

Why should JAXB care about this class, given that it's clearly transient for marhsalling & unmarshalling purposes?

How can I tell JAXB to ignore this field?  I'm aware that I could put a factory method on there, but it seems pointless, given that the factory won't be able to instantiate the value (which is why it's done in `afterUnmarshal`)

Comment: This bug sounds familiar (I'll investigate).  Have you tried a newer version, the current release is 2.3.2:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks for the follow-up, and for the headsup on the latest version.  Just tried with 2.3.2 (`2.3.2.v20111125-r10461`), and got the same error.  FYI - [The Maven Page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven#Available_Released_Versions) of the wiki is out of date, and only lists releases up to 2.2.0 (which is how I missed it).

Comment: I have posted an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9619140/383861) and updated the wiki page (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven#Available_Released_Versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in EclipseLink 2.2.0 that has been fixed in later EclipseLink releases.  You will still see this exception in the latest EclipseLink release if you use the default access (`XmlAccessType.PUBLIC`), but annotate the field:

```
package forum9610190;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Root {

    @XmlTransient
    private DateTime startTime;

    public DateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(DateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

}
```

**Option #1 - Annotate the Property**

Instead of annotation field, you can annotate the property (get method) with `@XmlTransient`:

```
package forum9610190;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Root {

    private DateTime startTime;

    @XmlTransient
    public DateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(DateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

}
```

**Option #2 - Annotate the Field and use @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)**

If you wish to annotate the field, then you will need to specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class:

```
package forum9610190;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlTransient
    private DateTime startTime;

    public DateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(DateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html